# Unable to use box plot with fixed LOD in tableau

Tags: tableau-api

According to my requirement, i need to use LOD in the Box plot which is not giving the exact chart[Please find the link for the report](https://drive.google.com/open?id=14LAWJkjKweOo2hFqss93vvUZFmWmHZLb) . In the attached workbook,the "With LOD" sheet is where i am using the LOD function .

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

PRoblem is not with LoD, problem is using `Median` function.

Any reason behind using the Median function in LoD?

If Median function is your necessity then tableau box plot behaving correctly.

More detail about median [here](http://www.purplemath.com/modules/meanmode.htm)

I have checked the attached data in workbook and found everthing is correct.

If you are seeing wrong then add data how exactly you want to see the data using LoD and Median together.